# Can a generator of the ring of integers of local fields can be chosen so that it is also a uniformizer at the same time?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, local-field

Let $L/K$ be an extension of local fields. We can find $\alpha$ such that $\mathcal{O}_L=\mathcal{O}_K[\alpha]$. What do we know about this generating element? I think that this $\alpha$ can be selected in such a way that, in addition to the above property, it is also a uniformizing parameter at the same time. But I can not prove it.

Comment: Thanks to Hensel lemma ?

Comment: @reuns in the Neukirch's book, this is proved by Hensel's lemma.

Comment: @reuns Ok, you are right. I have no claim on this part, that Hensel's lemma implies it solely. I take back my words about it. What do you mean by $q_L$ in your answer?

Comment: What is your guess ???

Comment: @reuns Guesses are made after a well enough familiarity with standard notations. I have no good guess. My bad guess: maybe $q_L$ is the norm of its unique prime ideal. But then I do not know how should I compute the norm of an ideal in the case of local fields. Probably it should be equal to the norm of the unique prime ideal of $K$, raised to the power $f$. Yet I do not have any idea about the norm of an ideal in the case of local fields. I don't know how much of the things I write here are wrong. I'm trying to learn, clarity helps my mind, riddles and ambiguity confuse me more.

Comment: The main theorem is that $\Bbb{F}_{p^k}=\Bbb{F}_p(\zeta_{p^k-1})$ this extends naturally to unramified extensions of non-archimedian local fields $(*)$ where $q$ is the size of the residue field. $(*)$ finite extensions of $Q_p$ or $F_p((t))$, complete discretely valued fields with finite residue field.

Comment: By the way, for any ring extension $S = R[\alpha]$ you can replace $\alpha$ by $u \cdot \alpha$ for any unit $u \in R^\times$, so in that sense you often have plenty of choice. Not as much as you would hope for here though, see answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at a *proof* that $\mathcal O_L = \mathcal O_K[\alpha]$ for some $\alpha$, such as Prop. 3, Chapter III, Section 1 in Lang's "Algebraic Number Theory" then you should be able to see that you can take as $\alpha$ either $\zeta$ or $\zeta + \pi$ where $\zeta$ is an arbitrary generator (modulo the maximal ideal of $\mathcal O_L$) of the residue field extension and $\pi$ is an arbitrary choice of uniformizer.  When $L/K$ is unramified we can take as $\pi$ a prime from $K$ and thus $\mathcal O_L = \mathcal O_K[\zeta + \pi] = \mathcal O_K[\zeta]$. When $L/K$ is totally ramified, we can use $\zeta = 1$ (or $\zeta = 0$), so $\mathcal O_L = \mathcal O_K[\pi]$.

Lang proves the result for an extension of DVRs with a separable residue field extension; no assumption of completeness, so in particular no use of Hensel's lemma.  But the assumption that the DVR downstairs has an integral closure in the extension of its fraction field that is also a DVR is not at all typical in a "global" situation such as the localization of a Dedekind domain, as there can be more than one prime upstairs lying over the prime downstairs.  In the complete setting things are nicer since every valuation ring of a local field is a DVR.

Answer (score 2):

$O_L=O_K[\pi_L]$ iff $f(L/K)=1$ and $O_L=O_K[\zeta_{q_L-1}]$ iff $e(L/K)=1$. In general it is $$O_L=O_K[\zeta_{q_L-1}+\pi_L]$$

Hensel lemma is needed to construct the root unity, then (in the non-trivial case $e\ne 1,f\ne 1$) we need a closed-ness and density argument, investigating $\zeta_{q_L-1}+\pi_L-(\zeta_{q_L-1}+\pi_L)^q$

Comment: What is $q_L$? What is $\zeta_{(q_L-1)}$? Is it the ${(q_L-1)}^{\text{th}}$ of unity?

Comment: The notation $q_L$  means the size of the residue field of $L$, since the size of a generic finite field is usually written as $q$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $\mathcal{O}_L = \mathcal{O}_K[\alpha]$ with $\alpha$ a uniformiser of $\mathcal{O}_L$, then the canonical inclusion of their residue fields $\mathcal{O}_K/(\pi_K) \hookrightarrow \mathcal{O}_L/(\alpha)$  is surjective.

Conversely, if the extension is totally ramified (which is what the above says), then ...

reuns' answer says the same and more.